# User Defined function in SQL not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT
    [DateAdded], [DateUpdated],
    [dbo].[firstchartoupper]([LastName]) AS [LastName],
    [FirstName], [NPI], [StreetAddress],
    [CITY], [ZIP], [STATE], [Organization],
    [ReportYearMonth], [FileUploadDate] 
FROM
    tt
```

`[dbo].[firstchartoupper]` is my custom user defined scalar function which I wrote

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[firstchartoupper]
     (@name AS NVARCHAR(255))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CHAR NVARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @rem NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(255);

    IF @name IS NULL
       RETURN NULL;

    SET @char = SUBSTRING(@name, 1, 1);
    SET @rem = SUBSTRING(@name, 2, LEN(@name));
    SET @output = @char + @rem;

    RETURN @output;
END
```

However, I'm getting an error

> Cannot find either column dbo or the user-defined function or aggregate scalar

Comment: Can you check the function is created or not in DB under the scalar function folder

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that SQL. Is your `SELECT` statement being run in the same database as the function was created in?

Comment: On a different note, what is that function trying to achieve? It's taking the value of `@name` and splitting into 2 parts and then concatenating them back. So, with a name .like `'Jones'`, it splits it into the parts `'J'` and `'ones'` and then concatenates them back to `'Jones'`. The function doesn't actually achieve anything.

Comment: Maybe he want to Get First Character in uppercase.

Comment: Then, @Ayan_84, they would have `SET @output = UPPER(@char)+@rem;`

Comment: The error is occuring on the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't actually do anything -- but it appears to "work" as in [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0948b6911596d65bd174c7e518733d28) db<>fiddle.

Is this the expression you want?

```
select stuff(str, 1, 1, upper(left(str, 1)))
```

This upper cases the first character in the string -- which seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: that is fine....i'm giving an example but the error is occuring in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Your function and the SQL that calls it correctly written.

Make sure to execute the SQL that creates the function **on the proper database** and before executing the `SELECT` that uses it (use `GO` as batch separator if on SSMS). You can use `USE DatabaseName` just before the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement to switch the current connected database.

Then use this query to find it:

```
USE DatabaseName

SELECT
    ObjectType = O.type_desc,
    SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(O.[schema_id]),
    ObjectName = O.name,
    CreatedDate = O.create_date,
    ModifiedDate = O.modify_date
FROM
    sys.objects AS O
WHERE
    O.type IN ('FN')
```

If it's **not** listed then it failed creation or you created it on a different database.

You can test your function without any table reference by directly supplying it a value:

```
SELECT dbo.firstchartoupper(N'Some testing value')
```

You can also try adding the database name before the schema if it's on another database:

```
SELECT DatabaseName.dbo.firstchartoupper(N'Some testing value')
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your function even exists in your database or not.

```
  select * from sys.objects where name = 'firstchartoupper' and type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
```

If this works fine then try your query with database name. like as below

```
        SELECT
            [DateAdded], [DateUpdated],
            [yourdbname].[dbo].[firstchartoupper]([LastName]) AS [LastName],
            [FirstName], [NPI], [StreetAddress],
            [CITY], [ZIP], [STATE], [Organization],
            [ReportYearMonth], [FileUploadDate] 
        FROM
            tt
```

GO

Answer (score 0):

Apparently , it seems sql server was not detecting the function.I just then ctrl+f5 and then f5 it in management studio.It worked

Comment: I doubt this was the solution, in truth. Ctrl+F5 is the short cut key in SSMS for Parse. I suspect we were being led down the rabbit hole a bit here; the OP wasn't getting an error that the object didn't exist at run time, but had a red "squiggly" line under the object name as they hadn't updated their intellisense. As a result they "thought" the object didn't exist, however, it did (just SSMS wasn't aware it did) and actually running the statement would have produced no error..